# Convert Chile Map with Inserts

Tags: shapefile, jvectormap

I have used the NaturalData states/Providences data set to generate a map of Chile using this command:

```
python converter.py \
    --width 900 \
    --country_name_index 12 \
    --country_code_index 31 \
    --where "iso_a2 = 'CL'" \
    --projection mill \
    --name "cl" \
    --language en \
    ne_10m_admin_1_states_provinces_shp.shp output/jquery-jvectormap-cl-mill-en.js
```

It generates a maps like this. (Minus the red circles)

[image: JVectorMap of Chile]

The three circled islands are all labeled ValparaÃso, which corresponds to the providence circled on the main land mass.

Looking at the documentation provided on how to do insets (which uses Alaska and Hawaii as examples), I attempted to move these islands closer, so that my map was more centered.

```
python converter.py \
    --width 900 \
    --country_name_index 12 \
    --country_code_index 31 \
    --where "iso_a2 = 'CL'" \
    --projection mill \
    --name "cl" \
    --language en \
    --insets [{"codes": ["CL-VS"], "width": 200, "left": 10, "top": 370}]' \
    ne_10m_admin_1_states_provinces_shp.shp output/jquery-jvectormap-cl-mill-en.js
```

Unfortunately, this fails with

```
converter.py: error: unrecognized arguments: 200, left: 10, top: 370},]' ne_10m_admin_1_states_provinces_shp.shp output/jquery-jvectormap-cl-mill-en.js
```

My questions:

1. How do I resolve the errors in that error message? The parameters are mentioned in both the documentation and in the code so I am unsure what should be used instead.
2. How can I move the three circled islands to be insets without affecting the mainland ValparaÃso?

Answer (score 0):

Your insets argument is failing because it isn't quoted properly.  You can use the following:

```
--insets "[{\"codes\": [\"CL-VS\"], \"width\": 200, \"left\": 10, \"top\": 370}]"
```